# Having trouble formatting GUI/ adding an action listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have searched far and wide through this website and through the Java website trying to figure out an answer to this, but I couldn't find an answer specific to my problem.

I'm not sure where to put my action listener for `b1` and `b2`, and I also think something may be wrong with the methods I'm using (although the code still compiles and runs and everything works fine without an action listener.)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CubeCalc  {

    public static void MakeTitlePage()
    {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
        b1.setBackground(Color.decode("#5A20DF"));
        b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        b1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Information about the Developer");
        b2.setBackground(Color.decode("#23D123"));
        b2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        b2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275,50));

        GridBagConstraints blo = new GridBagConstraints(); 
        blo.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        blo.gridx = 0;
        blo.gridy = 1;
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -//
        JPanel start = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        start.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        start.add(b1, blo);

        JPanel info = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        info.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        info.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        info.add(b2, blo);
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -//
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Cubic Feet Calculator"); //Creates Frame
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            /*  window.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Harold.jpg")));*/
                window.add(start, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                window.add(info, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        window.pack(); //resizes to minimum possible frame size
        //window.setSize(500,500); //Sets size of frame
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true); //Sets the frame to be visible
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -//
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MakeTitlePage();
    }
}
```

Where should I add my `ActionListener` and is there anything that I should be doing with my methods?

Comment: Well, the button references are local variables of the MakeTitlePage method, and are thus only accessible from this method, so the only place where to add action listeners is in that method. Note that, by convention, Java methods should always start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments on the snippet:

- Setting layout for the buttons is not necessary
- Add an `ActionListener` to the button using [`addActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29)
- Play nice with the Event Dispatch Thread, launch the frame from `main` using [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CubeCalc  {
    public static void MakeTitlePage()
    {
       final JFrame window = new JFrame("Cubic Feet Calculator"); // Creates Frame (created first so the button can reference it for JOptionPane

       JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
       b1.setBackground(Color.decode("#5A20DF"));
       b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
       //b1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); << unnecessary
       b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
       b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // action when button is pressed
            int pressCount=0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switch(++pressCount) {
                    case 1:  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Hey, stop pressing me!"); break;
                    case 2:  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "I said, stop pressing me!!!!"); break;
                    default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Aaaaaaaaargl!!!!"); break;
                }
            }
        });

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Information about the Developer");
        b2.setBackground(Color.decode("#23D123"));
        b2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        //b2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); << unnecessary
        b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275,50));
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // action when button is pressed
            int pressCount=0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switch(++pressCount) {
                    case 1:  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "There is no information here!"); break;
                    case 2:  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Stop asking me for information!!!!"); break;
                    default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Aaaaaaaaargl!!!!"); break;
                }
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints blo = new GridBagConstraints(); 
        blo.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        blo.gridx = 0;
        blo.gridy = 1;
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -//
        JPanel start = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        start.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        start.add(b1, blo);

        JPanel info = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        info.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        info.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        info.add(b2, blo);
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -//
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /*  window.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Harold.jpg")));*/
        window.add(start, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(info, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        window.pack(); //resizes to minimum possible frame size
        window.setVisible(true); //Sets the frame to be visible
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // launch frame on the Event Dispatch Thread
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 MakeTitlePage();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Effect:

[image]

Comment: Thank You! What difference does adding `final` to the part where the JFrame is declared make?

Comment: @Buttchinbro To refer to a variable in an enclosing scope, the variable needs to be declared as `final`. Just try remove the `final` and you will see a compile error.

Comment: and also, if I wanted to make it so pressing `b1` opened a new page and closed the original title page, would I launch the new GUI from the event dispatch thread or within the action listener?

Comment: @Buttchinbro Since the action listener already runs on the EDT, opening a new "page" as you call it will run from the EDT. Note that if you plan to launch a modal `JDialog` though, you best let current events on the EDT get handled by launching the dialog using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like :

```
 b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // what do you want to execute...

            }
        });
```